In a Dancer2 app, is there a way to show all active routes and to what method they are linked?
Very much like what we have in the typical Mojolicious 404 debug page.
I assume it is easy, I just couldn't find it anywhere.
Currently, I have this, but it doesn't give a complete list of all my routes:
get 'routes' => sub($app)
{
    my $routes = $app->routes();
    my %result = (
        paths => [
        map {
            my $method = $_;
            my @routes = $routes->{$method}->@*;
            my @paths =
                map {
                    my $route = $_;
                    my $regexp = $route->regexp();
                    "$method: $regexp";
                }
                @routes;
            @paths;
        }
        keys $routes->%* ]
    );

    return np %result, array_max => 10000000;
};


What's exactly terrible? What else do you want to know about each route?

Can't help. Not familiar with Dancer2. But wouldn't it help to provide an example of what your solution misses?

@ikegami, this does not show all routes, I can use routes not shown by this. And it's a hack, I'd assume Dancer would provide something like this out of the box.

That is not an example of what your solution misses. /// I don't see anything hackish about it. It's just a straightforward application of an interface that seemingly provides the routes (->routes). How is that a hack?

You should probably be using ->pattern instead of ->regexp() that would be why you're missing routes. Also, if this is being run in a Plack app, Dancer has no idea of other routes defined in the Plack context, meaning routes declared via Plack::Builder, and Plack middlewares will work but not be available here.
